# Comparing images in c# .net windows form application

Tags: .net

I am making a tic tack toe game in c# .net windows form application and i am planning on using images in the boxes instead of tick or cross.So i am facing a problem in comparing those images because in order to win the program has to check for identical images in a row or column or diagonal.I have searched but still found no solution.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should have a data structure separate from the on-screen images, to represent the board state.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using Properties.Resources.SomeImage.  Doesn't work, it creates a *new* image every time you use it.  A very naughty thing to do for a property btw.  You have to copy it into a variable so you use the property only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the wrong track; you shouldn't compare the images to decide whether a player has won.

Instead, you should have an internal representation of the game board (e.g. a bidimensional array) that contains, for instance, numbers (e.g. 0 for an empty cell, 1 for a cross and 2 for a circle), and work on that instead (it's much easier to compare numbers than images). The visual representation can easily be constructed from that grid.

In general, you should always keep the visual representation separate from the "logical" representation of data. The UI should only reflect the logical representation, and shouldn't be used by the actual program logic.

Comment: Thanks thomas i got your point.Feeling angry about the way i was iplementing before.Well thanks..

Comment: Any suggestions for AI?

Comment: @SalmanJaved, not really, but it's a common problem, I'm sure you can find tons of tic-tac-toe AI examples on Google ;)

Comment: Ok i have implemented a logic for AI but that's not working well.The computer plays in a way that if there are two "O's" in a row or column or a diagonal then it places another "O" in the third place and wins and if there are two X's then it places O in the third and blocks the player from winning and if none of the above options are available then it randomly plays i.e it places O in any of the boxes.So guyz i really need your help i have a project and i have to submit it tomorrow or never???

Comment: @SalmanJaved, it's completely unrelated to the original question, so you should ask a separate question. BTW, if it's a homework assignment, I strongly suggest that your question shows real effort to solve the problem by yourself, because StackOverflow members don't take kindly to people who ask for solutions without really trying by themselves...

Answer (score 0):

Comparing images can be done by taking image pairs and comparing value at each pixel, this will be very expensive task and will make your game much slower.

The correct way is you should declare a two dimensional array to represent value at cells. You can manipulate this array for spawning  ticks and cross. And in a separate function parse the array to create display. 
This way it will be much easier to check for game over or to create next move.

Comment: Nitish by your method i'll be able to check very easily that if a player has won or not.I should have done that.Right now i have implemented is such a way that it compares text int every button which is way more complex.thnx

Comment: Nitish i've completed the player to player tic tac toe now i am looking to implement it against computer.So any hints or suggestions because i am finding it a bit difficult.

Comment: You can get information about that in this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/15753572/4041735